# making an empty rectangle with Rafael JS

Tags: javascript, graphics

I am using Rafael 2.1.0 with JavaScript on Firefox 19.0.2 on Windows 7.

I would like to make a rectangle that is completely opaque around the edges but transparent in the interior.  Is this possible?

I have looked at

```
paper.rect.attr({fill:
```

but it appears to only have the option of the color to fill with.

```
paper.rect.attr({fill: 'red', opacity:0.0});
```

makes the edge disappear

```
paper.rect.attr({fill: 'red', fill-opacity:0.0});
```

produces an error in the JavaScript code (in that subsequent functions do not work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set strokes instead of fill and you might also alter strokes-width.

Actually setting strokes will let you set their color and setting strokes-width will let you edit their width in viewport units.

Comment: That worked for what I was asking for.  stroke-width does not appear to be supported. Spectrum.rect.attr({stroke: 'red', stroke-width:2, opacity:1.0}); gave an error of a missing colon at the hyphen as was also the case when I replaced stroke with strokes.  Thanks, Peter.

Comment: Providing stroke-width in a property object, you have to write it as a string : `{ stroke: "red", "stroke-width": 2, opacity: 1 }` . Otherwise yes it naturally explodes.